# JQuery - Can we capture both the p and div tags at a time in a single sentence using jquery?

Tags: jquery

JQuery - Can we capture both the p and div tags at a time in a single sentence using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the comma selector:

```
$("div, p")...
```

or [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$("div").add("p")...
```

Answer (score 3):

......

```
$('p, div')..........
```

Just separate each item with a comma (`,`).

*Alternatively*, you could use the **[add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)** function:

```
$('p').add('div')..........
```